# Gradle 6 dependencies with strict version and because keyword

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, dependency-management

## The problem

I'm currently experimenting with Gradle 6.0 and ran into the problem that I would like to combine the because statement with the syntax for e.g. strict and rejected versions.

## My buildscript:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation(group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api') {
        version {
            strictly '[5.0, 6.0]'
            prefer '5.5.2'
            reject '5.5.1' // for testing purpose only
        }
    }

    testRuntimeOnly(group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine') {
        version {
            strictly '[5.0, 6.0]'
            prefer '5.5.2'
            reject '5.5.1' // for testing purpose only
        }
    }

    // Force Gradle to load the JUnit Platform Launcher from the module-path
    testRuntimeOnly(group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher') {
        version {
            strictly '[1.5, 2.0]'
            prefer '1.5.2'
        }
    }
}
```

## What I've tried so far

I've currently tried to add the `because` statement below or above the `version`statement and adding curly brackets around them, but none of these things seemed to work out.

## The question

Is it possible to add the `because` statement to the last dependency and if yes, how?
It would be interesting too, to know whether I can combine both `testRuntimeOnly` into one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html), you can easily see exactly **what** is available to you. So converting your sample to use the Kotlin DSL, we have

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-api") {
        version {
            strictly("[5.0, 6.0]")
            prefer("5.5.2")
            reject("5.5.1") // for testing purpose only
        }
    }

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-engine") {
        version {
            strictly("[5.0, 6.0]")
            prefer("5.5.2")
            reject("5.5.1") // for testing purpose only
        }
    }

    // Force Gradle to load the JUnit Platform Launcher from the module-path
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform", "junit-platform-launcher") {
        version {
            strictly("[1.5, 2.0]")
            prefer("1.5.2")
        }
    }
}
```

> Is it possible to add the because statement to the last dependency and if yes, how?

Yes it is. Since I'm using the Kotlin DSL now, I can easily bring up intelli-sense:

[image: intelli-sense]

You can see here `because` is available *outside* the `version` block, so:

```
// Force Gradle to load the JUnit Platform Launcher from the module-path
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform", "junit-platform-launcher") {
    version {
        strictly("[1.5, 2.0]")
        prefer("1.5.2")
    }
    because("my reason here.")
}
```